# MongoDB: Выборка по массиву объектов

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с проблемой
Есть документы вида

```
 {
  _id: 5883e595e46735283e1cac1b,
  __v: 0,
  times: 
   [ { week: 0, s: 1, e: 3, _id: 5883e595e46735283e1cac22 },
     { week: 1, s: 3, e: 17, _id: 5883e595e46735283e1cac21 },
     { week: 2, s: 0, e: 0, _id: 5883e595e46735283e1cac20 },
     { week: 3, s: 5, e: 8, _id: 5883e595e46735283e1cac1f },
     { week: 4, s: 0, e: 0, _id: 5883e595e46735283e1cac1e },
     { week: 5, s: 7, e: 9, _id: 5883e595e46735283e1cac1d },
     { week: 6, s: 0, e: 0, _id: 5883e595e46735283e1cac1c } ],
  createdAt: 2017-01-21T22:49:57.074Z
 }
```

Нужно получить документы у которых:

week = 3
s >= 5
e <= 9

Т.е. найти объект в массиве с week=3, и посмотреть в этом же объекте значения s и е, если их значения соответствуют

```
{
   s: {
      $gte: 6
   },
   e: {
      $lte: 7
   }
}
```

Тогда найти запись приведенную выше.

Можно ли как то построить такое условие?

Answer (score 2):

Вот не поверите, убил на это сегодня пол дня. Как только написал нашел решение))

```
times: {
     $elemMatch:{
          week: 2,
          s: {
             $gte: 3
          },
          e: {
             $lte: 4
          }
      }

  }
```